# How can I add the degrees of freedom in tbl_summary in the gtsummary package in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, gtsummary

I am trying to report the degrees of freedom in the tbl_summary from gtsummary package in R but I can not find anything.

I would appreciate any help or guidance. Here is an example data set

```
iris %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by=Species,
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
  ) %>% 
  add_p()
```

Comment: Answer posted here: https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/932

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Can you add that as an answer here as well? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much @DanielD.Sjoberg, you are amazing